# Object doesn't support this property or method in mootools

Tags: mootools

Can any one tell me if the below line is correct in mootools?:

```
document.getElementById("step-1").getElements('.saved strong.savTitle').set('html', "Billing");
```

When i add this line to my jsp, "Object doesn't support this property or method" js error is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some small issues with this:

`document.getElementById('step-1')` in mootools should be `document.id('step-1')` - both return an element but the mootools one also installs prototype methods in older IE which does not inherit from Element prototype and it sets up an element uid and Storage.

Failure to do so in IE6,7 and 8, this will produce the error you are posting.

### second

when you get this error, you really need to break up the calls you do to see where in the chain it fails for debugging. I suggest saving a reference into a var and applying the method after.

### third

you are getting multiple elements and calling `.set()` on a collection - which MooTools will automatically apply to every member via a `each` loop. if you must use chaining on a collection and it's more than 1 action, you ought to do the `.each` yourself to avoid multiple repetitions.

### finally

you can anchor this in a single selector:

```
document.getElements('#step-1 .saved strong.savTitle').set('html', 'hai'); 
$$('#step-1 .saved strong.savTitle').set('html', 'hai'); // also same.
```

this will work fastest in a browser with QSA.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to select a UL with spaces in its class name. I need to change the style of this UL from "display:noe" to "diaply:block" .
This is the line:  <ul class="clean menu sec_accnt" style="DISPLAY: none">

Comment: sure. `ul.menu.sec_accnt` will do it.